# How to get the path of a running process if its pid of name is known in java on a windows system?

Tags: java, process, kill

I am writing a program to kill and start processes in another computer connected via lan. I am able to kill the process successfully. I used tasklist to list the process and taskkill for killing it. To start the killed program again the path of the process have to be obtained.

Is there a way that I can do it in java?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to kill a process by it's path, but you can always kill it by either it's process name or id.

Here's what I use to kill a process, e.g. firefox.exe.

1. Create a VB script as follows,

   ```vb
   sub killProcess(strProcessName)
       set colProcesses = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name='" & strProcessName & "'")
       if colProcesses.count <> 0 then
           for each objProcess in colProcesses
               objProcess.Terminate()
           next
       end if
   end sub

   killProcess "firefox.exe"
   ```
2. Now in order to run the above script via Java, use the Process API as follows,

   ```
   Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path_to_vbscript_file, null, null);   
   pr.waitFor();
   ```